# C# store and display calculated iteration in one line using messagebox.show

Tags: c#

I am working on this program. My purpose is to Store the result of calculated input data in one int[] variable and display it in one line using messagebox.show.

```
int[] data = new int[] { 65, 66, 67, 32, 100, 90 };        // I declare int[] data it contain my data that I want to work with the length change.
int[] array = new int[6];  // i declare a table length of 6
  foreach (var b in data)   // for every element in my data I want to do this operations and build my array.
    {
      array[0] = b / 200;
      array[1] = b / 79;
      array[2] = b / 27;
      array[3] = b / 19;
      array[4] = b / 21;
      array[5] = b / 3;


Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(" ", array));  // this line is for console application 
// output of this line is :
/*
0 0 2 3 3 21
0 0 2 3 3 22
0 0 2 3 3 22
0 0 1 1 1 10
0 1 3 5 4 33
0 1 3 4 4 30 */
MessageBox.Show(" "+ string.Join(" ", array)); // this line is for windowsform application
```

My purpose is in windowsform application to display my variable using messagebox.show. I aim the calculated to store them in one variable and to display them like this one :

```
0 0 2 3 3 21 0 0 2 3 3 22 0 0 2 3 3 22 0 0 1 1 1 10 0 1 3 5 4 33 0 1 3 4 4 30
```

I really appreciate any help.

kind regards

Comment: Change `WriteLine` to `Write`, and then call `Console.WriteLine()` after the `for` loop. Otherwise, you need to capture the result in a `string result` (or better yet, `StringBuilder`) during the loop, and then output `result` after the loop is done.

Comment: You have very little control over how MessageBox formats its text.  It is a convenience method to display a friendly message to tell the user something went wrong, it is quite inappropriate to display program results.  Use Label in a Winforms app, but only after you talked with the intended users of your program.  They'll ask for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join the string in loop and then display them outside of the loop in your message box. Use `StringBuilder` class for appending results.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(...)
{
  ...
  ...
  sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", string.Join(" ", array).Trim())
}

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, may I know please how I can convert StringBuilder in my case and change to an  `int` variable.